# Courier Font in PdfBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

How to use Courier font in PdfBox?

I tried to use 
     `((PDVariableText)field).setDefaultAppearance("/Cour 12 Tf 0 0 0 rg");`.

It throws this exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find font: /Cour
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processSetFont(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:179)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processOperator(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:132)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDDefaultAppearanceString.processAppearanceStringOperators(PDDefaultAppearanceString.java:108)
```

However, this works fine:

`((PDVariableText)field).setDefaultAppearance("/Helv 12 Tf 0 0 0 rg");`

Here is my maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
   <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the font to the default resources:

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.COURIER;
PDResources resources = new PDResources();
resources.put(COSName.getPDFName("Cour"), font);
PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
acroForm.setDefaultResources(resources);
```

(You need to adjust this if acroform already exists, or if the default resources already exist. This is taken from the [CreateSimpleForm.java](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateSimpleForm.java?view=markup) example from the source code download)

The "Helv" font doesn't throw an exception because PDFBox sets it as default, to behave like Adobe. But I'd still recommend that it is explicitely set in code.